# how to check performance of apache spark Job

Tags: python, performance, apache-spark, monitor

I have installed Apache Spark 2.3.1 and need to check which script is efficient

Questions:

1.How do I monitor Apache Spark script execution?

2.Which one of these scripts is efficient?

```
rdd = sc.textFile("Readme.txt")
```

1:

```
rdd.flatMap(x => x.split(" ")).countByValue()
```

2:

```
words = rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(" "))
result = words.map(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
```

Comment: Word count is not a very good word example of checking efficiency. Especially only running on one machine... Using Spark for that is overkill, and both examples provide very similar execution plans

Comment: After Execution, i check the UI, spark did not even made a execution plan , do we need to deploy it as an application for spark to make an execution plan?

Comment: I don't think `spark-shell` gives an execution plan, so yes, probably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use spark web ui, it contains for of the information you will need for monitor performance in terms of - time, executor stats, stage stats, task stats, resource stats etc.

Comment: After starting pyspark, i was able to open spark web UI at http://localhost:4040 thanks

Comment: do upvote and mark it ad accrpted if it helped. thanks